# How to hide a static UITableViewCell with a button in Swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview

Hi I have a table view with static cells. I want to hide specific ones with a button. I must hide them according to the current time of the iphone so i created UITableViewCell outlets for each of them. How can i hide a cell when the button is clicked ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I get what you want to do. if you want to hide action, you need to control your static tableView. 
Don forget to reload tableview in your action.

```
[self.tableView reloadData]; 
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.hidden=YES;
        return 0;
    }else{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.hidden=NO;
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
        cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: isnt this Objective-C ? I need to code in Swift. And by the way I also can hide a cell with just a UITAbleViewCell outlet. But it doesnt go away just the stuff it contains disappears. I think i need to set the cell height to 0.